# How to print a future time from system time in C. Such as if it is 10 am now, to print 12 am instead

Tags: c, datetime

I am currently learning C programming and i am trying to out put a time for the next scheduled flight of a mock airport. i though i could use the system time, then have that be modified so it out puts which ever time is 3 hours from that moment. However, i could only find solutions to out put the current time on the system. Any help would be appreciated.

I've tried a few different methods I've seen others do, but have had no luck in modifying them as of yet. I am still very new to C programming, so i cant read  many of these functions, and due to that cannot find where in them to edit or change out in order to achieve the desired result.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<time.h>

int main(){

    time_t t;
    time(&t);
    printf("\n right now the time is: %s",ctime(&t));

}
```

this outputs to "Mon Aug 12 10:00:17 2019"
my end goal is something similar to "12:00 pm" if the current time is 10 am

Comment: Show us what you've tried.

Answer (score 2):

In `t` the seconds since the unix epoch (1970-01-01 00:00 UTC) is stored.
So you can simply add `3h = 3600*3 = 10800` to it:

```
time_t t;
time(&t);
t += 10800;
printf("\n In 3 hours the time is: %s",ctime(&t));
```

Comment: Works for adding hours but not months or years.

Comment: @nicomp This is correct. Did I overread that requirement in the question?

Comment: Your answer is great, I'm just adding to it. No worries.

Answer (score 2):

Since flights are every 3 hours, I take `be modified so it out puts which ever time is 3 hours from that moment.`  to mean up to 3 hours from the current moment.

If so,

1) Avoid making the non-portable assumption the `time_t` is in seconds.

2) Convert to local time, do the math on the `.tm_hour` member.

```
time_t t;
if (time(&t) == -1) Handle_invalid_time();
printf("Right now the time is: %s",ctime(&t));

struct tm *tm = localtime(&t);
if (tm == NULL) Handle_invalid_conversion();

tm->tm_hour += 3;
tm->tm_min = 0;
tm->tm_sec = 0;

// re-adjust members to their usual range  (Handle going into next, day, month, year)
mktime(tm);

printf("Flight time: %s", asctime(tm));
```

Comment: Does `localtime()` handle the readjustment? The comment before it implicates that, but it doesn't seem to be true

Comment: Reading the [manpage of `time`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/time.2.html) : *the time as the number of seconds since the Epoch* I would expect that the assumption of `time_t` being in seconds should be portable.

Comment: @ctx, Oops, `mktime()`  does the "... with their values forced to the ranges ...".

Comment: @Gerhardh man page refers to usage within *nix and the assumption about `time_t` is portable there.  C does not require that.  For maximum portability, avoid that assumption.  C has "`time_t` which are arithmetic types capable of representing times" which could mean `time_t` is as `int, long long, double` or others.

Comment: Ah, I forgot about that nasty little detail. Thanks for reminding me.

Comment: @AntoineMathys The idea being that the flight times are fixed, on the 3rd hour as hinted in OP's "my end goal is something similar to "12:00 pm""